# Can't get the Profile instance that have logged user as field

Tags: django

So i have here a 'create_project' view where l’m trying to assigne to the 'owner' field of project instance created a 'profile of the current user logged . so it's show a error says:

> DoesNotExist at /projects/create-project/
>
> Profile matching query does not exist.

create_project view :

```
def create_project(request): # create operation
form = projectForm() 
if (request.method == "POST"):
    form = projectForm(request.POST,request.FILES) 
    if form.is_valid(): # check if it valid
        project = form.save(commit=False) 
        project.owner = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        project.save()
        return redirect("home")


context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'projects/project_form.html',context)
```

Project Model Class:

```
class project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Profile Model Class:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stacktrace. Did you create the `Profile` before trying to create a `Project`? Is there a reason you have `owner` as a profile instead of a user?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your implementation you should instead do;

`project.owner, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)`

`get_or_create()` will return the object and a bool for whether or not the object was created by the function call.

I'd also advise that you make the project owner a `User` foreign key rather than a `Profile`. I inherited a project that was setup like this, where an object was associated with the user profile. The majority of the time its details from the `User` object that we were interested in so the link would have made more sense to the `User`.

You should also consider using a signal to create the profile objects for a user. I do this using the `post_save` from `User`;

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def build_profile_on_user_creation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```